# How to restrict the Select pg_sleep(10) for READ_ONLY user in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a read only user in Postgres. I need to restrict the function pg_sleep() for that user. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you try `revoke execute on ...`?

Comment: I tried it. It restricts all the functions But my requirement is to restrict the particular pg_sleep function only.